# Gradle и jdk asm

Tags: java, gradle

В проекте, собираемом gradle, используется `jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm`.

build.gradle:

```
group 'GroupName'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
}
```

Метод main в IDEA запускается нормально, но не собирается через gradle: `Execution failed for task ':compileJava'`.

Выводит ошибки на все импорты и классы из `jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm`:

```
error: package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree does not exist
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.AbstractInsnNode;

error: cannot find symbol
public void add(final LabelNode first, final LabelNode second) {
```

Почему такое происходит? И как исправить? Решит ли проблему переход на ow2.asm?

**Update.** Минимальный пример:

```
package com.example;

import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.AbstractInsnNode;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnNode;

import static jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ICONST_0;


public final class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final AbstractInsnNode node = new InsnNode(ICONST_0);
    }
}
```

Лог:

```
error: package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree does not exist
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.AbstractInsnNode;
                                          ^
error: package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree does not exist
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnNode;
                                          ^
error: package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm does not exist
import static jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ICONST_0;
                                            ^
error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ICONST_0;
^
4 errors
:compileJava FAILED
```

Comment: а какая версия **gradle**?

Comment: Используется default gradle wrapper. В gradle-wrapper.properties: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip . Т.е. 3.3, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @VsSekorin, когда отвечаете человеку, пишите его имя после знака "@", тогда ему придет уведомление.

Comment: @RostislavDugin это не обязательно делать, если нет других комментариев.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ого, даже такая функция есть... Не знал!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение **javac**, что бы изменить поведение нужно добавить ключ `-XDignore.symbol.file`. Попробуйте вот этот вариант:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'GroupName'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

compileJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
    options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не решило проблемы. До этого тоже пробовал подключать gradle-lombok. И проект с lombok, но без jdk asm, при изначальном build.gradle проходят build.

Comment: мне не удается воспроизвести ошибку. вы можете добавить [mcve] в вопрос?

Comment: При любом использовании. Добавил минимальный пример в вопрос.

Comment: @VsSekorin добавьте его прямо в вопрос. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. Ссылки могут быть только дополнением.

Comment: @VsSekorin я изменил ответ. должен работать.